# RegEx Substring Extraction Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

How do i extract the first instance of the below pattern from string.

```
$a="CIC-284 Updated code to reflect changes from Defect 46"

$a -match "CIC-*"
True
```

> Expected result :  CIC-284 from the string using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression (`CIC-*`) matches the character sequence "CIC" followed by any number of hyphens. The asterisk is a [quantifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#quantifiers) with the meaning "zero or more times the preceding expression".

To match the character sequence "CIC-" followed by any number of digits change your expression to `CIC-\d*`. `\d` is an escape sequence that matches digits. Alternatively you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.